# How to create a Reactive Inbound Channel Adapter in Spring Integration Reactor

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-integration, project-reactor, reactor

I'd like to understand how to create a **reactive** channel adapter for Spring Integration with Reactor core. I've understood from other forums [I've read that this Mongo DB reactive adapter can be a good example](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/main/spring-integration-mongodb/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/mongodb/inbound/MongoDbChangeStreamMessageProducer.java), but it contains lots of Mongo domain specific classes.

I've read the Reactive part of the docs, and I see that there is a need to implement `MessageProducerSupport`, but from the code example it looks that there is a need of implementing a class the extends `MessageProducerSpec` and calls the first one. Can someone give an example for the most basic usage and explain what is really a demand for creating such a channel adapter? What I understand that I should do is something like:

```java
public IntegrationFlow buildPipe() {
   return IntegrationFlows.from(myMessageProducerSpec)
      .handle(reactiveMongoDbStoringMessageHandler, "handleMessage")
      .handle(writeToKafka)
      .get();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `MessageProducerSpec` is for Java DSL. It has nothing to do with low-level logic of the channel adapter. If you have a `MessageProducerSupport`, then this one is good enough for you to use in the flow definition:

```
/**
 * Populate the provided {@link MessageProducerSupport} object to the {@link IntegrationFlowBuilder} chain.
 * The {@link org.springframework.integration.dsl.IntegrationFlow} {@code startMessageProducer}.
 * @param messageProducer the {@link MessageProducerSupport} to populate.
 * @return new {@link IntegrationFlowBuilder}.
 */
public static IntegrationFlowBuilder from(MessageProducerSupport messageProducer) {
```

See more in docs about arbitrary channel adapter usage in the Java DSL: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/dsl.html#java-dsl-protocol-adapters

But again: forget about Java DSL API for your channel adapter. Implement that channel adapter first. Yes, reactive `MessageProducerSupport` must use `subscribeToPublisher()` in its `doStart()` implementation. The rest of the logic around building the `Flux` from source system is up to you and the library you are going to rely on.

There is also a `ReactiveRedisStreamMessageProducer` and `ZeroMqMessageProducer`, but I cannot say that their code is easier to digest than the mentioned `MongoDbChangeStreamMessageProducer`.

Comment: I’m struggling to understand what is the difference when adding the `Spec` layer. Isn’t `MessageProducerSupport` fit into the the Java dsl?

Comment: The `Spec` layer is only for syntax sugar - a builder pattern. The main component is a `MessageProducerSupport`. Yes, it simply can be used in the Java DSL. We definitely can live without syntax sugar.

Comment: I understand. Thanks. Btw, when using these two they should be beans? Or can I do `new MessageProducerSupportImpl()`?

Comment: If used in Java DSL, both of them can be with just plain `new`: the framework creates bean for us underhood.